# main.js 404 error for MIT react-starter-kit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browserify

I'm using Kriasoft's [react starter kit](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit), and I built a small app. Everything runs perfectly locally w/ Browserify, however when I try running the production server at /build/server.js, the main.js file gives a 404 error in the Chrome console and some of my code breaks.

I've done some research and looked around -- I think it has something to do with Browserify, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Can someone explain me what I'm doing wrong and what the root of the issue is? :)

[image: through browserify]
[image: through running node build/server.js]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is addressed [here](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/issues/370). The build needs to be run with the "release" option when testing without Browsersync/HMR/React Transform.

```
npm run build -- --release && node build/server.js
```

Otherwise, the bundle will not build properly.